# jQuery How to post specific array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, serialization

This is dynamic input-form

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="form1">

<input type='text' id='shipping' name='shipping[3]'>
<input type='text' id='payment' name='payment[3]'>
<input type='text' id='address' name='address[3]'>

<input type='text' id='shipping' name='shipping[4]'>
<input type='text' id='payment' name='payment[4]'>
<input type='text' id='address' name='address[4]'>

<input type='text' id='option' name='option'>
</form>
```

And my javascript(jQuery) post this form to PHP-Server Side

```
    $.post("phpfile", $('#form1').serialize(),
    function (data) {
    }
);
```

If use serialize(); it will post all data in input-form 
Example:

```
option: exampledata
shipping[4]: exampledata
payment[4]: exampledata
address[4]: exampledata
shipping[3]: exampledata
payment[3]: exampledata
address[3]: exampledata
```

I want post only specific data like **shipping** and **address** not payment Is there any way to do it?

```
shipping[4]: exampledata
address[4]: exampledata
shipping[3]: exampledata
address[3]: exampledata
```

Comment: $('#form input[name!=shipping]' input[name!=address]').serialize();

Answer (score 0):

Why are you searializing your input in this case? You can pass arrays and objects from javascript to php using the POST-PARAMETER without modification of the object/array.

```
var postArray = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
jQuery.post("index.php", {arrData: postArray }, function(data){

    console.log(data);

});
```

You can easily get the Array with PHP using `$_POST["arrData"]`

Answer (score 0):

Following is your answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form role="form" method="post" id="form1">

<input type='text' id='shipping' name='shipping'>
<input type='text' id='payment' name='payment[3]'>
<input type='text' id='address' name='address[3]'>

<input type='text' id='shipping' name='shipping[4]'>
<input type='text' id='payment' name='payment[4]'>
<input type='text' id='address' name='address[4]'>

<input type='text' id='option' name='option'>
<input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
<script>
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var formData = {};
   formData.shipping = $('#shipping').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your-server-file-name.php",
      data: formData,
      success: function(response){},
      error:function(error){}
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some points to remember

1. why you are giving name as  name='payment[3]',name='address[3]' etc?. This type of names are for multiselect elements.
2. you had not added submit button or any code to submit your form. It should be there to submit form (like I have added).

Note: I have processed only shipping. You can add all other elements that you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do, is declare an array, and then make use of the `^=` operator, which will look for every element with that name. I'd then use the `.each()` function to create a loop that iterates at the count of my elements. I can then `.push()` my values into my declared array. Then I'd loop through my array in my other file where the data is sent to, *"phpfile"*, as you named it.

Example:

```
var shippingArray = [];

$('input[name^="shipping"]').each(function() {
    shippingArray.push( $(this).val() );
});

var addressArray = [];

$('input[name^="address"]').each(function() {
    addressArray.push( $(this).val() );
});
```

You now have 2 perfect array variables that you can parse to any file you'd like. I'd suggest you look into jQuery AJAX.

So in the file, *"phpfile"*:

```
$shippingArray=$_POST['shippingArray'];
$shippingValues=array_values($shippingArray);

$addressArray=$_POST['addressArray'];
$addressValues=array_values($addressArray);

$i=0;
$length=count($shippingArray);

while($i < $length) {
    $i++;
    $arrayValue=$shippingArray[$i];

   //Do something with the value
}

$i=0;
$length=count($addressArray);

while($i < $length) {
    $i++;
    $arrayValue=$addressArray[$i];

   //Do something with the value
}
```